# How do I turn all text on an HTML page into a single string while keeping the CSS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace all text within each HTML element in an HTML document with a single character "A".

Suppose I have a page like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
    <h2>This is some smaller text</h2>
    <h3>This is even smaller text</h3>
    <div id="some-important-id">
       <div id="something"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
  // put the code here
  </script>
</html>
```

I need all the **text** in a page to be converted to the letter "A", but we don't want to change the `div`, because it contains child HTML elements not text.

What I needed:

```html
<h1>A</h1>
<h2>A</h2>
<h3>A</h3>
<div id="some-important-id">
  <div id="something"></div>
</div>
```

We don't touch the `div`, because it may contain some useful code for it.

Comment: It's not clear what you really intend. Which element should that single `A` go into?

Comment: Do you mean `<h1>A</h1><h2>A</h2><h3>A</h3>`?

Comment: I recommend posting what the actual expected outcome is. What you are asking isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the elements on the page. If the element only contains a single text node, then it's a leaf element with text. Replace its text with `A`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
  if (el.childNodes.length == 1 && el.childNodes[0].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    el.innerText = 'A';
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
    <h2>This is some smaller text</h2>
    <h3>This is even smaller text</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is there a `div` wrapping all the text inside?

Comment: To demonstrate that that the div is *not* being replaced. The result maintains all the HTML structure of the original.

Comment: So that's why  we also check for text nodes...

Answer (score 0):

This code selects all elements in the body of the HTML document using `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")`. Then, it loops through each element and replaces its inner text with the letter "A" repeated for the length of the original inner text. This is likely a test or demonstration of manipulating the DOM using JavaScript. Hope it helps you!

```js
    var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var characterCount = element.innerText.length;
      element.innerText = "A".repeat(characterCount);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
    <h2>This is some smaller text</h2>
    <h3>This is even smaller text</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('*')` will return container elements, not just leaf elements.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. There are different ways for this issue. I am not sure that what they exactly want.

Comment: all leaf nodes: `document.querySelectorAll("*:not(:has(*))")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS and implement something like like

```
// Get the root element of the HTML document
var rootElement = document.documentElement;

// Function to recursively traverse the DOM and extract text content
function extractTextFromElement(element) {
  var text = '';

  // If the element is a text node, concatenate its content
  if (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    text += element.textContent.trim();
  }
  // If the element has child nodes, recursively extract text from each child
  else if (element.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      text += extractTextFromElement(element.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }

  return text;
}

// Call the function with the root element
var extractedText = extractTextFromElement(rootElement);

// Print the extracted text as a single string
console.log(extractedText);
// Get the root element of the HTML document
var rootElement = document.documentElement;

// Function to recursively traverse the DOM and extract text content
function extractTextFromElement(element) {
  var text = '';

  // If the element is a text node, concatenate its content
  if (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    text += element.textContent.trim();
  }
  // If the element has child nodes, recursively extract text from each child
  else if (element.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      text += extractTextFromElement(element.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }

  return text;
}

// Call the function with the root element
var extractedText = extractTextFromElement(rootElement);

// Print the extracted text as a single string
console.log(extractedText);
```